# How to test a method that uses FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()

Tags: java, junit, mocking, mockito, junit5

I'm trying to test a part of my code that in certain cases ends up calling `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()` and we are not in a jsf context it gives null and I receive an NullPointerExcetption

How can I test that part?

My code

*Test Method*

```
@Test
void testCambiarNombre() {
    
    ModificarUsuarioBean modificarUsuarioBean = new ModificarUsuarioBean();
    modificarUsuarioBean.setFachada(fachada);
    modificarUsuarioBean.init();
    
    modificarUsuarioBean.getUsuario().setNombre(null);
    modificarUsuarioBean.cambiarNombre(); // Here is the problem. See code of method below
    
    assertTrue(fachada.existeUsuario("admin", null));
}
```

*ModificarUsuarioBean.cambiarNombre*

```
public void cambiarNombre() {
    if(StringUtils.isBlank(usuario.getNombre())) {
        FacesMessagesUtils.mostrarMensajeDelProperties("usuario.accion.cambiarNombre.error.VACIO", "comun.ERROR", FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN); // Here is the problem. See code of method below
    } else {
        
        if(fachada.modificarNombreUsuario(usuario)) {
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            UsuarioLogueadoBean usuarioLogueadoBean = (UsuarioLogueadoBean)context.getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("usuarioLogueadoBean");
            usuarioLogueadoBean.getUsuario().setNombre(usuario.getNombre());
            FacesMessagesUtils.mostrarMensajeDelProperties("usuario.accion.cambiarNombre.OK", "comun.EXITO", FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO);
        } else {
            FacesMessagesUtils.mostrarMensajeDelProperties("usuario.accion.cambiarNombre.error.REPETIDO", "comun.ERROR", FacesMessage.SEVERITY_WARN);
        }
    }
}
```

*FacesMessagesUtils.mostrarMensajeDelProperties*

```
public static void mostrarMensajeDelProperties(String keyMensaje, String keyCabecera,
        FacesMessage.Severity severidad) {
    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(severidad, MessageUtils.obtenerMensajeDelProperties(keyCabecera),
            MessageUtils.obtenerMensajeDelProperties(keyMensaje));
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg); // Here is the NullPointerException
}
```

*pom.xml*

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.junit.jupiter/junit-jupiter-engine -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
        <version>5.9.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-core -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
            
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mockito/mockito-junit-jupiter -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-junit-jupiter</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

My version os Java is 8

Answer (score 0):

`FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()` is a static method. So `MockedStatic` can be used to test the required flow

```
@Test
void testCambiarNombre() {
    try (MockedStatic<FacesContext> context = mockStatic(FacesContext.class)) {
        FacesContext facesContext = mock(FacesContext.class);
        context.when(FacesContext::getInstance()).thenReturn(facesContext);
        when(facesContext.getExternalContext()..).thenReturn(..)
        //...
    }
}
```